# Running a Lisp function on AutoCAD startup

Tags: vba, autolisp

I'm using a Lisp program to load a VBA macro into AutoCAD. The Lisp program below is autoloaded into AutoCAD on startup

```
(defun C:LoadDVB ()
  (command "vbaload" "WindowsDoors.dvb")
)
```

However I still have to type "LoadDVB" into AutoCAD's command line to get the plugin to work otherwise it gives me an error. I need to automate this step so that on startup I can just use the VBA plugin.

Comment: I don't have experience with AutoCAD, but is there any reason you can't just call the same in you initialization function?  Or just have `(command "vbaload" "WindowsDoors.dvb")` instead of the `(defun …)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your autoloader is creating a new command, and *that command* is what loads your VBA macro.

In this case `(defun C:LoadDVB () ...)` is defining a function called "LoadDVB" that you can run at the command line. The code inside the function loads your VBA macro... but this code doesn't run until you call the function at the command line.

If you want your autoloader to load your macro directly, take out the function definition. All you need is one line that reads `(command "vbaload" "WindowsDoors.dvb")`.